# CakePHP 3rd Level Association for Pagination

Tags: cakephp, model, pagination, associations

I'm a little confused after reading the Cookbook and other SO posts here..

I have the following 3 level relationship:

```
Project (has customer_id) -> Customer (has user_id) -> User
```

I want to be able to pass in **User** conditions into my Projects paginate function. How can I do that? I take that I have to connect between the three models properly which I'm not doing currently...

---

**ProjectsController** looks like:

```
$this->paginate = array(
            'contain' => array('Customer' => array('User')),
            'order' => 'Project.id ASC',
            'conditions' => $condition,
            'limit' => $limit
        );
```

**Project Model** has:

```
public $belongsTo = 'Customer';
```

**Customer Model** has:

```
public $belongsTo = 'User';
public $hasMany = array('Order', 'Project');
```

**User Model** has:

```
public $hasOne = array(        
        'Customer' => array(
            'className' => 'Customer',
            'conditions' => array('User.role' => 'Customer'),
            'dependent' => false
        )
```

Comment: `I want to pull out the User data into the parent "level":` - easily doable but: why?

Comment: It would allow me to work with the Paginate function more easily. I'm trying to be able to paginate my Projects view on User data.

Comment: So you want to join across 3 tables - Why don't you ask how to do that, instead of something that sounds like a superficial change?

Comment: Yeah you're right, I'm not sure why I framed it like that.. I'll reword it!

Answer (score 0):

### Use a join

The only thing required to do be able to filter/sort based on user fields is to achieve sql of the form:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM 
    projects
LEFT JOIN
    customers on (projects.customer_id = customers.id) 
LEFT JOIN
    users on (customers.user_id = users.id)
```

If it's only for the purpose or filtering/sorting - one of the simplest ways to do that is to just inject a join:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'contain' => array('Customer'),
    'order' => 'Project.id ASC',
    'conditions' => $condition,
    'limit' => $limit,
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'users',
            'alias' => 'User',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Customer.user_id = User.id',
                // can also define the condition here
                // 'User.is_tall' => true 
            )
        )
    )
);

// only projects where the user is tall
$results = $this->paginate(array('User.is_tall' => true));
```

### Use an "exotic" association

Alternatively, bind an association directly from the Project model to the User model:

```
$this->Project->bindModel(array(
    'belongsTo' => array(
        'User' => array(
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Customer.user_id = User.id',
                // can also define the condition here
                // 'User.is_tall' => true 
            )
        )
    )
));

$this->paginate = array(
    'contain' => array('Customer', 'User'), // <- different
    'order' => 'Project.id ASC',
    'conditions' => $condition,
    'limit' => $limit
);

// only projects where the user is tall
$results = $this->paginate(array('User.is_tall' => true));
```

In either case the executed sql will include two joins, one dependent upon the other.